# Error while updating kali linux on vmware

Tags: vmware, kali-linux

So i recently updated my Kali Linux VM. I have started getting this error and i don't know what it means. Tried googling it but i didn't find any solutions. Maybe i am not using the right keywords.

```
root@kali:/home/kali/Downloads/opt# apt update
Get:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org stable/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]                                                                                         
Get:3 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages [17.6 MB]                                                   
Get:4 http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main amd64 Packages [266 kB]                      
Get:5 http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main i386 Packages [265 kB]                                                                   
Get:6 http://security.debian.org stable/updates/main Translation-en [142 kB]                                                                            
Hit:7 http://ftp.debianclub.org/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                               
Get:8 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main i386 Packages [17.5 MB]                                                          
Hit:9 http://old.kali.org/kali moto InRelease                                                        
Get:10 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Contents (deb) [39.5 MB]
Get:11 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/main i386 Contents (deb) [39.1 MB]                                                                                                      
Get:12 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages [105 kB]                                                                                                         
Get:13 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Contents (deb) [118 kB]                                                                                                   
Get:14 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages [209 kB]                                                                                                        
Get:15 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/non-free i386 Packages [177 kB]                                                                                                         
Get:16 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/non-free i386 Contents (deb) [874 kB]                                                                                                   
Get:17 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Contents (deb) [923 kB]                                                                                                  
Fetched 117 MB in 14s (8,526 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 26, in <module>
    col.create(db)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 95, in create
    self._fill_commands(con)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 143, in _fill_commands
    self._parse_single_contents_file(con, f, fp.stdout)
  File "/usr/share/command-not-found/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 239, in _parse_single_contents_file
    l = l.decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 58: invalid start byte
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
root@kali:/home/kali/Downloads/opt#
```

I tried

> apt --fix-missing install

It got completed successfully but no change in the result when i run apt update and apt upgrade

Any fixes? Here is my sources.list file

```
root@kali:/home/kali/Downloads/opt# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# Debian packages for stable
deb  http://ftp.debianclub.org/debian/ stable main contrib
# Uncomment the deb-src line if you want 'apt-get source'
# to work with most packages.
# deb-src http://debmirror.hbcse.tifr.res.in/debian/ stable main contrib

# Security updates for stable
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib


deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
#deb http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
#deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib
# deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
root@kali:/home/kali/Downloads/opt#
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by simply commenting thefollowing repo in my sources.list.

> deb http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib

I am not sure how it got fixed as i still don't understand what the actual issue was but for now, this is a fix :)